# How to get all ERC721 tokens deployed on the smart contract

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, erc-721, openzeppelin

I have deployed a basic ERC721 token with some image metadata. I want to build a dashboard to view all the tokens and looking for an effective way of doing it.

One approach I have tried is:

> Loop through all the tokens given the number of tokens deployed and make a request for each tokenURI as shown below:

```js
var numTokens = 10
var datas = []

for (let i = 0; i < numTokens; i++) {
  let data = await contract.methods.tokenURI(i);
  datas.push(data);
}
```

Here, for `10 tokens` 10 requests will be made and 100 requests for `100 tokens` which seems very ineffective. What would be an effective way to list all tokens in the dashboard?

Answer (score 2):

Check the MakerDao [Multicall.js](https://github.com/makerdao/multicall.js) a library that allows multiple calls to smart contracts with a single JSON-RPC request.